# Format SD Card on Mac to update LCD screen on CR-10S Pro

Tags: firmware, creality-cr-10, lcd-screen, microsd

I want to update the LCD screen on my CR-10S Pro.

I've been following the procedure on [Teaching Tech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SBX30GmM3Qo) and formatting the SD card to FAT32, but the screen either shows the loading screen as normal or doesn't transfer anything.

How can I update the LCD?

[image: LCD Showing no files transferred]

Answer (score 1):

On a Mac it is easy enough to format an SD card to FAT32 using diskutils, but this doesn't do it quite properly.
Many resources state that for devices like the LCD on the CR10s Pro, the SD card must also be formatted with an "Allocation Block Size" of 4096, and unfortunately diskutils doesn't do this.

You can force the correct settings using `newfs_msdos` to format the card in terminal. The process that worked for me is:

```
diskutil list
```

Note the location of the sd card, something like `/dev/disk1` (be careful to select the correct device)
Then to format:

```
diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk1
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -v {name} -b 4096 /dev/disk1
```

where `{name}` is the name you want to give the SD card. When you put the card in the slot on the LCD, it should now update correctly.